# Star rating system second option changes the first with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a star system made with html and css only.

My issue is that when I change the rating of the second system the first one changes too. I tried to use different class names but apparently I am missing something. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<div style="padding-top:20px;" class="row">
  <div style="border-right: solid #4a98b5; width:290px;" class="col-
md-4"><p>Product Matches description</p></div>
  <div style="font-size:20px;color:#FFD700" class="col-md-4">
   <fieldset class="rating1">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating1" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" ></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating1" value="4.5" /><label class="half" for="star4half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating1" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating1" value="3.5" /><label class="half" for="star3half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating1" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating1" value="2.5" /><label class="half" for="star2half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating1" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating1" value="1.5" /><label class="half" for="star1half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating1" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating1" value="0.5" /><label class="half" for="starhalf"></label>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:20px;" class="row">
 <div style="border-right: solid #4a98b5; width:290px;" class="col-
md-4"><p>Rate your experience</p></div>
<div style="font-size:20px;color:#FFD700" class="col-md-4">
<fieldset class="rating2">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating2" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" ></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating2" value="4.5" /><label class="half" for="star4half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating2" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating2" value="3.5" /><label class="half" for="star3half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating2" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating2" value="2.5" /><label class="half" for="star2half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating2" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating2" value="1.5" /><label class="half" for="star1half"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating2" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating2" value="0.5" /><label class="half" for="starhalf"></label>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

.rating1 {
 border: none;
 float: left;
 }

.rating1 > input { display: none; }
.rating1 > label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating1 > .half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating1 > label {
  color: #ddd;
 float: right;
}


.rating1 > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating1:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating1:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating1 > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when 
changing rating */
.rating1 > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating1 > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current 
selection */
.rating1 > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }

.rating2 {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating2 > input { display: none; }
.rating2 > label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating2 > .half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating2 > label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}


.rating2 > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating2:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating2:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating2 > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating2 > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating2 > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating2 > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

Please have a look https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weYbzZ for the code.

Comment: You have 2 elements with the same id, that's generally a bad idea. Consider using class instead of id.

Comment: @GregorySpicer the fieldsets have different classes. Do you mean to use class for the inputs?

Comment: Exactly what I meant, and it looks like that was your issue, good work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by invalid HTML which should have been caught in the first place with the use of the validator.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!

Although the fieldsets have different class names, the input fields have the same names, hence when the second input field changes, it changes the first one. So different id names on the input fields solves the issue

Comment: Different id names are a requirement of HTML and your mistake would have been found easily if you used the HTML validator as everyone should.